# Oracle PL SQL disable all constraints of database tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I try to disable all constraint of all database tables. The database is named "database_test". The performance is not a problem.

I wrote a pl/sql script which give me all constraints with the table.

My problem is : when I run the script SQL developper say me "ORA-00972: identifier is too long". But I use only the fields already defined in the database.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DISPLAY_CONSTRAINT_DATABASE AS 
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (SELECT DISTINCT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE' AND OWNER = 'DB_NAME')
    LOOP
        FOR j IN (SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS WHERE owner = i.OWNER AND table_name = i.OBJECT_NAME AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE='R')
        LOOP
            dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement('alter table "DB_NAME.' || i.OBJECT_NAME || ' DISABLE CONSTRAINT ' || j.CONSTRAINT_NAME);
        END LOOP; 
    END LOOP; 
END DISPLAY_CONSTRAINT_DATABASE;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your double quotes are wrong. You are generating SQL statements like this:

```
alter table "DB_NAME.FOOBAR disable constraint some_constraint;
```

Which misses the second double quote (my guess is that you probably wanted to put the second quote *after* the table name which would have been wrong as well).

You need to put each part of the identifier in quotes, not the whole thing:

```
alter table "DB_NAME"."FOOBAR" disable constraint some_constraint;
```

I also don't see the necessity to use dbms_sql:

```
execute immediate 'alter table "DB_NAME"."' || i.OBJECT_NAME || '" DISABLE CONSTRAINT ' || j.CONSTRAINT_NAME;
```

To avoid having to repeat the owner, I would actually change the statement to:

```
execute immediate 'alter table "'||j.owner||'"."' || i.OBJECT_NAME || '" DISABLE CONSTRAINT ' || j.CONSTRAINT_NAME;
```

Thus you only need to "hard-code" the owner name once in the procedure.

Comment: Thank you. Now SQL developer say me "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges". However, I'm connected in 'system' with all privileges.

Comment: @jedema - `SYSTEM` has `ALTER ANY TABLE` through the `DBA` role only, I think, so that wouldn't be available in a definers-rights procedure. You could do this as `SYS`, but you should not be creating your own objects in either schema. Why aren't you doing this under the `DB_TEMP` schema?

Comment: @jedema: the question is: why are you using the `SYSTEM` account in the first place? You should be using a regular user (most probably the one for which you want to disable the constraints). Btw: `DB_NAME` does not denote a "database" it denotes a "schema" (or "user" in Oracle).

Comment: I don't know how to use DB_TEMP.
A very great thank you @a_horse_with_no_name because if I use another user it works. At the beginning I used "SYSTEM" beause in another account I had not privileges to access DBA_OBJECTS table. But now, with ALL_OBJECTS its works.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Can you remove the two brackets superfluous at the end of "execute immediate" line please. I can't edit for 2 characters. Otherwise these lines don't work. Thank you.